# Angular ng test cause error if I have types "node" in compiler option

Tags: angular, jestjs, tsconfig

**env**

- Angular 9
- node v10.16.0
- npm:6.9.0

with angular application, `ng test` fails if I added types in compileroption in tsconfig.json.

errors are like

```
Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha` and then add `jest` or `mocha` to the types field in your tsconfig.
```

```
S2304: Cannot find name 'expect'
```

my tsconfig is as below.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "types": ["node"],  // <= this part
  }
}
```

I know if I remove that `types`, then it works. But actually because of package which I use, I need to have it.

I hope someone has any knowledge about such behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In official google documentation there is no types option inside angularCompilerOptions property :
exhaustive list of available options :

1. allowEmptyCodegenFiles
2. annotationsAs
3. annotateForClosureCompiler
4. disableExpressionLowering
5. disableTypeScriptVersionCheck
6. enableIvy
7. enableResourceInlining
8. enableLegacyTemplate
9. flatModuleId
10. flatModuleOutFile
11. fullTemplateTypeCheck
12. generateCodeForLibraries
13. preserveWhitespaces
14. skipMetadataEmit
15. skipTemplateCodegen
16. strictMetadataEmit
17. strictInjectionParameters
18. strictTemplates
19. trace

if u need node types you can just use npm i @types/node to install them and the types are added under this hierarchy :

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "types" : ["node", "lodash", "express"]
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. On my application, I use buffer and it asks me to add types["node"], but even if I added it into "compilerOptions" it shows error TS2591: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. only when I added it in "angularCompilerOptions", it works well. Do you think it's because of some config setting ?

Comment: I found a solution; add "types":["node"] in tsconfig.app.json instead of tsconfig.json, application & test works well. Thank you fo much

Answer (score 1):

Answer myself

remove types  from `tsconfig.json` and add it in `tsconfig.app.json`

tsconfig.json

```
   // "types": ["node"], // remove
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"] // <= add
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```